# Encapsulation in Java(public member variables)

Tags: java, encapsulation

Can anyone provide an example in java wherein Encapsulation is not implemented and its impact.

I know wrapping of member variables and its methods is encapsulation.
Also its said that member variables should not be declared public(most cases) so that they are not exposed because anyone can use their values for these fields and can conflict with other users.

Now,Even if we declare the member variables as public,every instance(object) of the class will be allocated different memory.So even if a user sets the variable directly without using setters and getters,it wont affect the other user as he has different memory allocated,right? So how can it create conflicts?

The only scenario would be if there are requirement changes at a later point such as validation etc where the class will have to be changed accordingly. so if anyone could give an example for an scenario(with java code)other than the above where encapsulation is not implemented and its impact?

Comment: I wouldn't say that `wrapping of member variables` with simple getters / setters is encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

> Encapsulation can be described as a protective barrier that prevents
>   the code and data being randomly accessed by other code defined
>   outside the class. Access to the data and code is tightly controlled
>   by an interface.
>
> The main benefit of encapsulation is the ability to modify our
>   implemented code without breaking the code of others who use our code.
>   With this feature Encapsulation gives maintainability, flexibility and
>   extensibility to our code.

and

> Benefits of Encapsulation:
>
> - A class can have total control over what is stored in its fields.
> - The fields of a class can be made read-only or write-only.
> - The users of a class do not know how the class stores its data. A
>     class can change the data type of a field and users of the class do
>     not need to change any of their code.

From: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_encapsulation.htm

Answer (score 0):

Just as a basic example:

```
public class ArrayIter{
    public int at = 0;
    public Object[] arr;

    public ArrayIter(Object[] arr){
        this.arr =  arr;
    }

    public Object next(){
        if(at >= arr.length)
            return null;

        return arr[at++];
    }
}
```

Now let's assume two objects have access to the same instance of this class. Now this would be a valid operation:

```
ArrayIter iter = getArrIter();
iter.arr = null;
```

Which is going to result in unexpected behaviour (`NullPointerException` to be precise) as soon as `getArrIter().next()` is called.

Comment: The OP wants a use-case that demonstrates valid use of `public` fields in a class.

Comment: @ChetanKinger as far as i understood the question OP wanted an example for missing encapsulation and it's impact.